# jQuery validate : multiple form, single validation

Tags: jquery

I have 2 forms, namely (ids mentioned) 'add_product' and 'edit_product'

Now I am using jQuery validation plug-in, both the forms have same validation (similar to mentioned in following example)

```
jQuery("#add_product").validate({
    rules: {
        name:"required",
        price:"number"
    },
    messages: {
        name:"Please enter Plan Name",
        price:"Enter a valid number"
    }

});
```

and

```
jQuery("#edit_product").validate({
    rules: {
        name:"required",
        price:"number"
    },
    messages: {
        name:"Please enter Plan Name",
        price:"Enter a valid number"
    }

});
```

I want to combine them into 1 rule/function, how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the options in a variable and reuse it.

```
var vProduct = {
    rules: {
        name:"required",
        price:"number"
    },
    messages: {
        name:"Please enter Plan Name",
        price:"Enter a valid number"
    }
};

jQuery("#add_product").validate(vProduct);
jQuery("#edit_product").validate(vProduct);
```

Unfortunately you can't simply use `jQuery("#add_product, #edit_product").validate({...})` because the plugin doesn't handle more than one element being selected.

Comment: I need to ask you something, generally for jQuery '$' is used, why here 'jQuery' is used, is it valid?

Comment: @I-M-JM, 'jQuery' is used when there may be a conflict with another library that uses '$', e.g. Prototype or Mootools. It's completely valid, but is just more to type.